# Treat 3D numpy arrays as 3D image

Tags: image, numpy, rgb

I am generating 3D numpy arrays which I am hoping to treat as 3D image volumes. I do not want to use PIL package as I still need to keep working on arrays, but PIL converts them to Image objects.

My understanding is that any 2D slice of the 3D volume can be treated as an image, and should have three dimensions, say `(437, 268, 3)`, 3 being the RGB values. However, I am not getting this when I do image.shape, I get (437, 268).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Amir

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to display an image? Possibly trying to display a 2D matrix as an image?

Comment: Once I can get this, I will convert the RGB image to grayscale. At the current form, I am converting a (437,268) array to grayscale, and I am getting a (437,) 1D array, which is not what I want. Hope this clarifies it.
Once I have it as 2D grayscale image, I am going to use various hashing functions on it.

Comment: @AmirHashempour You most probably already have a grayscale image. How did you read your image? Using opencv, you should do `img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 1)` to get a RGB image. Then you can display it using `cv2.imshow("image", img)`

Comment: @TirthPatel Thanks for your comment. I am not reading any image, this is a 3D numpy array I have generated and I am hoping to use [whash](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) on. imageHash only accepts Image objects (from PIL package), hence trying to convert my numpy arrays into images, use whash, and then convert back to arrays.
Found out that if I convert in "L" mode, it automatically generates a grayscale image of the numpy array: `array_from_image = np.array(Image.fromarray(array).convert('L'))`

Comment: @AmirHashempour You may be generating the wrong shaped arrays. To generate a 3D array from a uniform distribution use something like `np.random.rand(437, 268, 3)`.

Comment: @TirthPatel the 3D arrays are some output from another software and they are 3D volumes with values (like MRI images), so I guess they should be fine? I guess because I can view slices in color, they are on the correct? When I go `plt.imshow(array[:,:,315])`, for example, I get an image that has values in each pixel.

Comment: The 3D array is a gray-scale volumetric image. A slice from it is a gray-scale 2D image. You don’t have RGB values. If you need to convert it to RGB for whatever reason, simply stack three copies of the array along the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was going to use the [imagehash](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) library to calculate the hash values of the image slices in z-direction, I ended up doing this:

`original` is my original array
`original_pil` is my `Image` object of the `original` array

```
import imagehash

import PIL

original_pil = np.zeros((original.shape[0], original.shape[1], original.shape[2]))

hash_diff = np.zeros((original.shape[2]))


for i in range(original.shape[2]):

    
    original_pil[:,:,i] = np.array(Image.fromarray(original[:,:,i]).convert('L'))

    hash_diff[i] = str(hash1 - imagehash.whash(Image.fromarray(original_pil[:,:,i])))
```